# TimeoutError trying to send an email with smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to use Python's smtplib module to send an email but I keep receiving a `TimeoutError`.

```
import smtplib

def send():
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)  # Email and password are already defined
        print('Enter recipient: ')
        recipient = input()
        print('Enter subject:')
        subject = input() + '\n'
        print('Enter body:')
        body = input()
        server.sendmail(email, recipient, body)
        server.quit()

    except TimeoutError as e:
        print (str(e))
```

This code recieves a:

`[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: Maybe connection issue or firewall?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a VPN connection, disable it first. It worked for me.

Comment: you could share your result with us. A little piece of a picture maybe enough

Comment: perfect, worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use port 587. I was getting the same error but when I entered 587 as port it worked

```py
smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not enabled "Allow Less Secure Apps" option in your GMail account.

Here's more officially from Google, 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I already enabled this setting, but i am still not connecting. I am thinking if trying to increase my timeout range:                                     import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(120) Could this possibly work?

Comment: @user7722705: Don't just ask, try it!

Comment: Note that Google disabled this setting, I believe in 2022. See note at the link above. From my understanding, it is now not possible to access smtp.gmail.com from a VPN connection. That is, regardless of authentication method or port.